# Get function pointers for array appending

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to determine whether an item should be looped and pushed, or directly pushed to an array.

For this, I have created the following code:

```
interface Item {
  prop1: string;
  prop2: string;
  prop3: string[];
}
```

For `prop1`, `prop2`, `prop3` I need its data in a single string array for each property. So I want to get the corresponding function pointer:

```
const items = [...] as Item[];
const collectProperties = ["prop1", "prop2", "prop3"];

// Contains the function pointers for every prop in collectProperties
const appendOperations = [] as ((array: string[], element: any) => void)[];

// Extract function pointers for each prop-type
collectProperties.forEach((element, index) => {
  appendOperations.push(
    Array.isArray(items[0][element as keyof Item])
      ? (array: string[], element: any) =>
          element.forEach((value) => array.push(String(value)));
      : (array: string[], element: any) =>
          array.push(String(element))
  );
});

// Appending items based on its type
items.forEach((item) => {
  appendOperations.forEach((fn, index) => {
    fn(
      // ... some array,
      // ... some value
    );
  });
});
```

I feel like there should be a more compact, elegant way of doing this. I know this can be done in the loop itself as well, but this means there will be an if-check in every property of every element, which is not desired when processing huge chunks of data. Help is appreciated.

Comment: What is `items` in that code?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder `items` is a collection of elements of the `Item`-interface, updated the OP

Comment: What is the loop at the end supposed to be doing?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Applying the append-operations which it derived before, omitting an if-check in every element

Comment: Yes, I get the using a function dispatch instead of an `if` check, but where does its information come from?

Comment: Let me clarify something - do you expect all of the items in the array to have the same shape? As in, for the same key, you'd get exactly the same type of value from all items in the array. Is this correct?

Comment: @VLAZ - They said it's an array of `Item`, so I'd think so.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder but then in another comment, turned out there might be subclasses of `Item` and for one reason or another, they might have different types for the same key. Right now if the first item in the array has a string for `prop2` but the second item in the array has an array of strings, then the function that is going to be generated is going to treat the array as one value and not spread its content into the `array` parameter. I wonder if this is a scenario worth considering for an answer or not.

Comment: I'd prefer to generate a function that handles either array or plain value, thus adding to `appendOperations` without branching (instead handling that in function when called).

Comment: @VLAZ - I thought they were talking about maintenance, code evolution, not subclasses. But fair enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of things you can do to tighten up the first bit:

- Make `collectProperties` an array of `keyof Item` rather than an array of strings, so you don't have to use a type assertion later
- Use `map` to build `appendProperties` rather than creating the array and pushing to it, since it's a one-to-one operation; this also lets you infer its type from the `map` return type

```typescript
// *** Use the type on the array so you don't have to use a type assertion later
const collectProperties: (keyof Item)[] = ["prop1", "prop2", "prop3"];

// Contains the function pointers for every prop in collectProperties
// *** `map` is a bit more idiomatic and helps a bit with setting types
const appendOperations = collectProperties.map(propName => {
    // *** Avoiding using `items` for this check since there's no need to make this function
    // dependent on `items`
    return propName === "prop3"
        ? (array: string[], element: any) =>
            element.forEach((value: any) => array.push(String(value)))
        : (array: string[], element: any) =>
            array.push(String(element));
});

// Appending items based on its type
// *** `forEach` is fine, but you could also avoid making functions using `for-of`
for (const item of items) {
    for (const fn of appendOperations) {
        fn(
            // ... some array,
            // ... some value
        );
    }
}
```

For the loop at the end, I couldn't get enough of an idea what it should be doing, but you might consider `for-of` rather than `forEach` just to avoid creating unnecessary functions, etc.

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJKQLbIN4FgBQyyADlAPbECMAXMgM5hSgDmA3AUaRQEy0NMg2HEuWIBmPoxYBtALrt8AXwIEA9KuQAVABbA6yPcgBWAVwbIYZKMjDaUxADZwAns3ImQAEwA09MsgB3FABrEAD-AO04MGQAA2BMOliDfQCE7TITGKiANxZ6YggEYBhgBGQIBwgMCHB9S2sEgk8ipygUBDIQcwTqulp0arkFNQ0AKgnkAFU6FFs550LkLps7ZDgoKBc-ZGdM5E8ugHJsuBy5-zMUOBtF67pZqDBgFadIKAJO7pjOhyqEMAABVE0GeEH6yAAFMEIHsYGhMABKOTIAC8yGkACIuFRMb5saJuHjkASKGJMfIVPh1MgAMJdMBwUD6eYWDwAl4gEhkUDvepWCrnKDOEQUAxc37-IEgp7AcGjZATMZxDBwYjJQw3ABGCWQGCsKGAnheque5TgXmQdgcxH02t1aVs9AgYGegluhTony65jVhS8AHlCltnj60chJUVpRRQXK6AA6VXESE4gBycBqaIAfDhhEQaUrkABBHI843usz5eKJZINVaGBB2BDBeigJCraAQI76ED+EAQCCeGz+VUw+v1dmhkB55A0lr+lrgZZc6t9WIz9pgExQLlpjMoVGHkk48kzohEAD8UI2W2ckgEzDkvkq1VqYFoFuciOzZ-Pf5fNTgPGDQAKKINokKQjkcAOCYEAfiAX7ZusmwuPGxBmBBADKUiCFBMFwYiRG-kQtCQjeLj3jIsjPlUgHvusiHfqiWYkX+KG3uhmGQjhD6QgBb5EQoiiIiM1IaEWxALvkvQYPoWpwLMQ4rAkLJ3AqhaxKB4EavUoAQL4WpZLs+ydCYDhDjBdD+GcZZ6nAwT5DAk6cvolbulpVgALRkDA674HWkJfD0mDLPCsl0N+eCEOegXBTEMBcr56xSbUnhBtA0SuVFbGJZCbF-jS8bFX4mYUc43gFeeRUldZmbQbBEBsaJM7KEoBBAA)

Comment: The reason I can't do `return propName === "prop3"` is because when I extend my properties later in Item-interface or the data returns differently (like prop2 is suddenly also an array), I also have to dive in this part to change it.

Comment: @Starfish - True. If that's a concern, I'd be tempted to create a "model" `Item` and derive the type and the check from that, rather than tying the function to the `items` array ([like this](https://tsplay.dev/WJ4x6N)). Or pass the `items` array into the function, but even then, if the array is empty it's problematic. :-)